# Atualizar UI de fragment após voltar da BackStack

Tags: android, android-fragment

Talvez o problema seja simples, mas de qualquer modo, estou me enrolando para conseguir fazer isso. Eu sei que teria como fazer isso através de interfaces, mas eu não quero desse modo. O meu app tem somente uma `Activity` que abriga muitos `Fragments`. A `Activity` implementa o padrão de design `Navigation Drawer`. Ela inicialmente exibe um `Fragment`. Pense desta forma:

`Fragment 1` > `Fragment 2` > `Fragment 3` > `Fragment 4`.

A maioria dos `Fragments` são listas. Agora siga a sequência, eu clico em um item do `Fragment 1` e vou para o `Fragment 2`, clico em um item do `Fragment 2` e vou para o `Fragment 3`. Agora no `Fragment 3`, eu pressiono em um item, seleciono uma opção (de um `DialogFragment` e vou para o `Fragment 4`.

Meu `Fragment 4` é uma tela que tem dados para serem salvos no banco de dados e que alguns deles são exibidos no `Fragment 3`. Eu tenho a opção de editar esses dados e salvar, ou então, apenas acessar o `Fragment 4` e não fazer nada, desistindo de salvar e voltando para o `Fragment 3`.

***O meu problema é o seguinte:*** se eu acessar o `Fragment 4` e não salvar, voltando para o `Fragment 3`, nada deve acontecer, apenas a transação voltar ao normal mesmo, ou seja, como a transação está no `Backstack` ela será revertida. Agora, se eu acessar o `Fragment 4` e salvar os dados, eu devo voltar para o `Fragment 3` e atualizar a interface do mesmo. Por exemplo, vou para o `Fragment 4`, depois de salvar os dados, dou um `popBackStack()` e volto para o `Fragment 3` atualizando a sua interface, ao invés de voltar para o `Fragment 3` de onde parou que é o que acontece.

Tentei fazer isso com o método `public void onBackStackChanged()` no `Fragment 3` mas esse método é chamado sempre que ocorre qualquer mudança na `BackStack`, ou seja, só de eu acessar o `Fragment 3` a partir do `Fragment 2` ele já é chamado.

Comment: Lucas, se você já faz a comunicação entre a `Activity` e os `Fragments` pq não faz a atualização dessa forma? Ao salvar os registros no BD no `Fragment4` por que não notifica a `Activity` para atualizar o `Fragment3`? Quando ele é removido (o `Fragment3`) eu acho que ele ainda fica `Attached`, basta dar find por tag. Consegue verificar esse hipótese? Infelizmente estou sem meu ambiente de desenv por perto para testar.

Comment: @Wakim eu queria uma forma bem mais simples de se fazer isso. Quanto ao `Fragment 3` mesmo depois que ele é removido e a transação adicionado ao `Back Stack`, a instância do `Fragment` ainda existe. Eu poderia sim fazer dessa forma mas acredito que deva ter uma forma vamos dizer "prática" de se fazer isso.

Comment: Uma forma simples, mas exige um pouco de trabalho inicial mas depois fica fácil. Apesar de nunca ter usado eu sugiro usar `EventBuses`, é uma forma simplificada de `Listeners`. Dê uma olhada em libraries que implementam esse conceito.

Comment: Ok. Vou dar uma pesquisada e volto aqui com o que achei sobre isso.

Comment: De uma olhada nessas libraries: http://square.github.io/otto/, https://github.com/stickyd/eventbus e http://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/.

Comment: @Wakim tentei fazer da seguinte forma ao invés de utilizar bibliotecas externar. Colocar o método que atualiza a UI (E inicializa no caso de quando é chamado pela primeira vez) dentro do método `onActivityCreated()`. O problema disso é que eu uso um `ListView` com `CustomAdapter` e os itens ficam duplicados quando eu retorno da `BackStack`. Tentei setar o `ListAdapter` para null sempre antes de atualizar a UI mas não adiantou.

Comment: O onActivityCreated é chamado mais de uma vez? Estranho... Porque não limpa o Adapter (`clear`) e refaz a carga chamando `notifyDataSetInvalidated` ou `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: Não é estranho, é porque ele é chamado quando é criado e quando volta da `BackStack` também. Vou tentar isso que você disse. Você por acaso sabe utilizar `loaders` com custom adapter?

Comment: Nunca utilizei `loaders`, sempre usei `AsyncTask` e criei o meu próprio `Adapter` extendendo da classe `BaseAdapter`. A princípio é só recarregar, mas poderia ter uma forma esperta de saber se deveria ou não (no caso de haver alteração no BD).

Comment: Eu faço o mesmo que você mas só para listas customizadas. Listas com itens padrões eu utilizo loaders pois ele mesmo já sabe quando atualizar ou não. Queria saber também se o mesmo conseguiria fazer com listas customizadas.

Comment: infelizmente não consigo ajudar, estou em falta com essa parte de Loaders. Foi até bom conhecer, vou dar uma estudada nisso depois.

Comment: @LucasSantos tentou fazer essa validação no onResume? Ele vai ser chamado sempre que o Fragment for interagir com o usuário.

Comment: @NetoMarin estou tentando implementar um custom loader. Se eu conseguir aviso aqui.

Comment: @NetoMarin consegui resolver meu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o meu problema utilizando `Custom Loader` para o meu `Custom Adapter`. A dificuldade ficou apenas em implementar o `Loader`, mas graças a esta implementação, não foi preciso comunicar um `Fragment` com outro ou com `Activity`. Quando eu estava em um `Fragment` e voltava  para o outro `Fragment` através do `popBackStack()`, o loader simplesmente recarrega atualizando os dados.

Se quiserem entender um pouco mais sobre `Loaders` veja [aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22342/o-que-s%C3%A3o-loaders-como-implementar-um-loader-para-carregar-do-banco-de-dados-se/22343#22343)

Comment: Legal @LucasSantos! Realmente usar o loader sempre é uma boa solução. Depois, seria legal vc criar um gist ou algo assim para compartilhar o código ou a idéia dele pelo menos :)

Comment: @Neto Marin sabe se eu posso fazer uma pergunta aqui e eu mesmo responder como se fosse tipo um tutorial ensinando a utilizar um custom loader? Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: tem sim, é inclusive incentivado caso vc encontre a solução. Veja um post, em inglês: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Neto Marin obrigado. Vou fazer assim que possível.

Comment: @NetoMarin criei a pergunta, veja em: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22342/o-que-s%C3%A3o-loaders-como-implementar-um-loader-para-carregar-do-banco-de-dados-se/22343#22343