# O que são Loaders? Como implementar um loader para carregar do banco de dados sem content provider e como implementar um custom loader?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-loader

Na internet, pelo menos em minhas pesquisas, achei pouco material sobre Loader em português. Por isso deixo aqui registrado esta pergunta, para ter respostas documentadas para a comunidade de programação android como fonte de pesquisa, consulta e estudo.

1. O que são Loaders?
2. Como implementar um Loader para carregar dados diretamente do
   banco de dados sem a necessidade de criar um ContentProvider?
3. Como implementar um Custom Loader para carregar dados que são
   utilizados em Custom Adapter e Custom Lists?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***Atenção, esta resposta é indicada para programadores que tenham pelo menos um conhecimento básico de:***

1. Activity
2. Fragment
3. Lists e Adapters
4. Custom Lists e Custom Adapters

**Loaders**

Introduzido no Android 3.0, os loaders fazem ser mais fáceis o carregamento de dados de maneira assíncrona nas Activitys e Fragments. Loaders tem as seguintes características:

- Eles estão disponíveis em cada Activity e Fragment.
- Eles proveem carregamento de dados de maneira assíncrona .
- Eles monitoram a fonte de seus dados e entregam novos resultados quando o conteúdo é modificado.
- Eles automaticamente reconectam para o último cursor do loader quando estão sendo recriados após uma mudança de configuração. Portanto, eles não precisam re-consultar seus dados.

**Resumo da API do Loader**

Essas são as múltiplas classes e interfaces que estão envolvidas no uso dos loaders em uma aplicação. Elas são resumidas nesta tabela:

[image: Classes envolvidas com Loader]

***OBS: Esta tabela foi montada a partir da tabela que se encontra no site oficial da documentação do android sobre loader. Eu peguei a tabela deles, traduzi, montei em um editor de texto, tirei print e então editei a imagem. Referências para os sites se encontram no final do post.***

Referências para as classes / interfaces:

- [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html)
- [LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html)
- [Loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html)
- [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)
- [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html)

As classes e interfaces na tabela acima são os componentes essenciais que você vai usar para implementar um Loader em sua aplicação. Você não vai precisar de todos elas para cada Loader que criar, mas você sempre vai precisar de uma referência ao LoaderManager para inicializar um Loader e uma implementação de uma classe Loader como CursorLoader.

**Usando Loaders em sua aplicação**

Uma aplicação que usa Loaders tipicamente incluirá o seguinte:
OBS: PRESTE ATENÇÃO NO ITEM 3 A SEGUIR, A PARTE EM NEGRITO.

1. Uma Activity ou Fragment.
2. Uma instância do LoaderManager.
3. **Um CursorLoader para carregar dados apoiados por um ContentProvider. Alternativamente, você pode implementar sua própria subclasse de carregador ou AsyncTaskLoader para carregar dados de alguma outra fonte.**
4. Uma implementação de LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks. Isto é onde você cria novos Loaders e gerencia suas referências a Loaders existentes.

Vimos um pouco sobre Loader e as classes que estão envolvidas em sua implementação. Você reparou no item 3 acima? Eu pedi para reparar. Na documentação, de onde foi retirado o texto acima, ele diz para utilizar um CursorLoader para carregar dados a partir de um ContentProvider, mas eu não quero isso.

Vou ensinar a como carregar dados diretamente de um banco de dados SQLite sem precisar criar um ContentProvider. Faremos isso a partir de uma biblioteca disponibilizada publicamente. Porém, vale lembrar, que poderíamos implementar nosso próprio Custom Loader se não quiséssemos utilizar a biblioteca. Mas fique calmo, ainda ensinarei a implementar um Custom Loader.

[Biblioteca cwac-loaderex](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex)

Independente de como vocês criam o seu banco de dados, a biblioteca precisa utilizar uma referência a SQLiteOpenHelper, então tenha um método onde seja possível o retorno de tal objeto.
Com a biblioteca importada para o seu projeto e supondo que você já tenha uma referência para SQLiteOpenHelper, vamos utilizar como exemplo um ListFragment que quer exibir uma lista de fabricantes que está armazenado no banco de dados e quer utilizar um SimpleCursorAdapter para vincular esses dados a lista.

Classe **FabricanteListFragment**
Essa classe apresenta apenas os métodos e comandos necessários para a implementação, ignorando o resto.

```
/**
 * Classe que exibe uma lista de fabricantes que estao cadastradas no banco de dados.
 * O usuario pode cadastrar, editar e deletar um fabricante. Esses fabricantes sao utilizados somente para selecionar o fabricante do instrumento.
 *
 * @author Lucas Santos
 *         Date: 28/03/2014
 *         Time: 09:11:20
 */
public class FabricanteListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /** O ID unico do Loader. ID's dos Loaders sao especificos para a Activity ou Fragment em que eles residem. */
    private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

    /** Referencia a interface callback no qual iremos interagir com o LoaderManager. */
    private LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> loaderCallbacks;
    /** O adapter que vincula nossos dados para o ListFragment. */
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    /** Um Loader para um cursor que carrega dados diretamente de um banco de dados ao invés de utilizar Content Provider. */
    private SQLiteCursorLoader loader;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        String[] projection = { Fabricante.COLUNA_NOME.texto };
        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };

        /*
         * Inicializa o adapter. O cursor do adapter e null. Nos iremos passar o cursor somente quando tiverem seu carregamento finalizado pela primeira vez.
         * Exemplo: quando LoaderManager entrega os dados para onLoadFinished. Passango a flag 0 como ultimo argumento do adapter, isto previne que o adapter
         * registre um ContentObserver para o Cursor (CursorLoader ira se encarregar disto para nos).
         */
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_fragment_item_drawer, null, projection, to, 0 );

        // Associa o adapter, agora vazio, com o ListView
        setListAdapter( mAdapter );

        /*
         * A Activity ou Fragment (que implementa a interfce LoaderCallbacks<D>) e o objeto callback do qual iremos interagir com o LoaderManager.
         * O LoaderManager usa este objeto para instanciar um Loader e para notificar o cliente quando os dados estao disponiveis/indisponiveis.
         */
        loaderCallbacks = this;

        // Indica que este Fragmento gostaria de participar no preenchimento do menu de opcoes recebendo uma chamada para onCreateOptionsMenu e metodos relacionados.
        setHasOptionsMenu( true );
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onActivityCreated( savedInstanceState );

        /*
         * Inicializa o Loader com o id "LOADER_ID" e callback 'loaderCallbacks'. Se o Loader nao existe, um e criado. Caso contrario, o Loader ja existente e reutilizado.
         * O chamada ao initLoader assegura que o loader está inicializado e ativo. São duas as respostas a essa chamada:
         * Se o loader especificado já existe, o último loader criado será reutilizado.
         * Se o loader especificado não existe, o initLoader inicia o método onCreateLoader dentro de LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.
         * Aqui é onde você implementa código para instanciar e retornar um novo loader.
         * Em ambos os casos, o LoaderManager ira gerenciar o Loader sobre o ciclo de vida da Activity/Fragment, ira receber qualquer novos Loaders uma vez que estiverem completados,
         * e ira relatar estes novos dados de volta para o objeto 'loaderCallbacks'.
         */
        getLoaderManager().initLoader( LOADER_ID, null, loaderCallbacks );
    }

    /*
     * Instancia e retorna um novo Loader para um dado ID.
     * É um método de fábrica que simplesmente retorna um novo Loader. O LoaderManager vai chamar esse método quando ele for o Loader pela primeira vez.
     */
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader( int id, Bundle args ) {
        // AQUI eu obtenho referência para um objeto `SQLiteOpenHelper` através da minha classe de banco de dados.
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance( getActivity().getApplicationContext() );

        // Criamos o Loader através da biblioteca sem a menor dificuldade, apenas passando o `context`, objeto `SQLiteOpenHelper`, uma `Query` e os argumentos null.
        // `Fabricante.GET_ALL_FABRICANTES.texto` é uma `Query` em forma de String que fará a consulta ao banco de dados. Como eu não utilizo a clausula WHERE, então o quarto parâmetro é null.
        loader = new SQLiteCursorLoader( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), databaseHelper, Fabricante.GET_ALL_FABRICANTES.texto, null );

        return loader;
    }

    /*
     * Chamado quando um loader criado préviamente tem seu carregamento finalizado.
     * Este método é geralmente onde o cliente irá atualizar a interface do usuário do aplicativo com os dados carregados.
     * O cliente pode (e deve) assumir que novos dados serão retornados a este método cada vez que novos dados são disponibilizados.
     * Lembre-se que este é o trabalho do Loader, monitorar a fonte de dados e realizar os carregamentos assíncronos reais.
     * O LoaderManager receberá esses carregamentos uma vez que tenham concluído, em seguida, passar o resultado para o método onLoadFinished do objeto callback
     * para o cliente (ou seja, a Activity/Fragment) para usar.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished( Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data ) {
        this.loader = (SQLiteCursorLoader) loader;

        // O carregamento assincrono esta completo e os dados agora estao disponiveis para uso. Somente agora podemos associar o cursor consultado com o Adapter.
        mAdapter.swapCursor( data );
        // O listview agora exibe os dados consultados.
    }

    /*
     * Chamado quando um loader criado préviamente está sendo resetado, fazendo com que seus dados fiquem indisponíveis.
     * É chamado quando os dados do Loader está prestes a ser resetado. Este método dá a você a oportunidade para remover
     * quaisquer referências a dados antigos que podem não estar mais disponíveis.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset( Loader<Cursor> loader ) {
        // Por algume razao, os dados dos Loader's estao agora indisponiveis. Remova qualquer referencia para os dados antigos substituindo ele com um Cursor null.
        mAdapter.swapCursor( null );
    }
}
```

Como a classe está TODA comentada, não vou comentar sobre a classe aqui, ***analisem o código***.

Utilizar está biblioteca é realmente muito fácil. Agora depois de terem utilizado e implementado, testem como o Loader carrega automaticamente quando uma mudança é detectada. Experimentem colocar um método que exclui um fabricante da lista ou então adiciona, mas façam isso sem sair do Fragment da lista. Mas como? Por exemplo, coloque para quando apertar um item da lista, aparecer um Dialog perguntando se quer deletar, você confirma dizendo que sim e então realiza a exclusão no banco de dados. A tela irá atualizar automaticamente.

Deem uma olhada na documentação da biblioteca, ela fornece métodos para o seu Loader criado a partir do SQLiteCursorLoader para inserir e deletar do banco de dados sem precisar criar uma AsyncTask para isso. A criação da AsyncTask está encapsulada dentro do método fornecido pela biblioteca. Por exemplo, na lista acima se você quisesse excluir um registro no banco de dados utilizando o seu Loader bastava apenas fazer isso:

```
// Usando este metodo com um SQLiteCursorLoader ele automaticamente e executado em uma AsyncTask, ou seja, fora da Thread Main.
loader.delete( Fabricante.NOME_TABELA.texto, Fabricante.COLUNA_ID.texto + " = " + idItemSelecionado, null );
```

***Simples não? :)***. Estarei explicando em outra resposta como implementar um Custom Loader para carregar dados de uma classe e retorná-los para exibição em uma Custom List que utiliza um Custom Adapter.

---

Referências:

- [Loaders - Documentação Oficial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#summary)
- [Entendendo sobre Loaders](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html)
- [Implementando um Custom Loader para uma Custom List com Custom Adapter](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/android-custom-adapter-listview-with-listfragment-and-loadermanager-inside-fragmentactivity/)
- [Biblioteca para criar CursorLoader sem utilizar ContentProvider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex)

Comment: Obs.: nome de linguagem/frameworks/tecnologias (Android, SQLite) [não devem ser realçados como código](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas); imagino que a tabela é um scan de algum livro, sendo assim é importante citar a fonte.

Comment: @brasofilo desculpe, não sabia que não deveria ser realçado como código. Eu sempre fiz isso para dar destaque diferente do negrito. Mas irei mudar este hábito e colocarei destaques em negrito somente. Quanto a tabela eu já coloquei a fonte, que foi o site do google. Eu peguei a tabela deles, traduzi em um documento do libre office, tirei print, editei a imagem e coloquei aqui.

Comment: *No problem*, eram só observações editoriais (normalmente, a origem de uma imagem é citada logo abaixo dela, mas se é sua produção, tudo azul). Excelente resposta por sinal :)

Comment: Obrigado. Vou editar a pergunta depois de qualquer modo, retirando os realces.

Comment: Parabéns pelas respostas. Foram muito úteis para mim! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Agora vamos ver como utilizar um custom loader para carregar dados de um custom adapter.

**Atenção, esta resposta é indicada para programadores que tenham pelo menos um conhecimento básico de:**

1. Activity
2. Fragment
3. Lists e Adapters
4. Custom Lists e Custom Adapters

Para entender a resposta acredito que você tem que ter as seguintes classes:

1. Classe Modelo - Entidade (Por exemplo, uma classe Pessoa que contém nada MAIS nada MENOS que apenas atributos e métodos getters e setters.
2. Um custom adapter, implementando talvez um padrão ViewHolder.
3. Activity ou Fragment que você usa para implementar a lógica da tela e carregar os dados. Neste exemplo será usado um Fragment.

Vamos começar com a classe modelo. Exemplo de uma classe modelo com atributos e métodos getters e setter. Ela é a entidade que contém os dados que são armazenados no adapter e no banco de dados:

Classe **Instrumento**:

```
/**
 * Classe que representa um instrumento.
 *
 * @author Lucas Santos
 *         Date: 29/04/2014
 *         Time: 11:24:20
 */
public class Instrumento {
    /** ID do instrumento no banco de dados. */
    private long id;
    /** Nome do instrumento. */
    private String nome;
    /** O numero de serie deste instrumento, unico para cada um. */
    private String numeroSerie;

    // ... Aqui teriam muitos outros atributos.


    public Instrumento( long id, String nome, String numeroSerie ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.numeroSerie = numeroSerie;
    }

    // ---------------------------------- INICIO dos getters e setters ----------------------------------
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome( String nome ) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNumeroSerie() {
        return numeroSerie;
    }

    public void setNumeroSerie( String numeroSerie ) {
        this.numeroSerie = numeroSerie;
    }

    // ... Aqui teriam muitos outros getters e setters.
    // ---------------------------------- FIM dos getters e setters ----------------------------------
}
```

Agora imaginando que você tenha aí seu custom adapter implementando ViewHolder, que recebe uma lista de instrumentos no construtor e que estende BaseAdapter, você irá acrescentar o seguinte método, caso não tenha um:

```
/**
 * Define uma lista para este adapter.
 *
 * @param data A lista será utilizada pelo adapter.
 */
public void setList( List<Instrumento> data ) {
    listInstrumentos = data;
}
```

Vou explicar o porque desse método, você tem que entender o porque de acrescentar porque as vezes você pode não estar estendendo de BaseAdapter mas sim de ArrayAdapter por exemplo e o ArrayAdapter já te fornece um método para executar algo parecido. A função desse método que eu falei para acrescentar nada mais é do que definir uma lista para o seu adapter. Ele vai servir para definirmos **null** quando o **loader** for resetado. Ele não será usado para definir a lista do adapter em si porque o adapter no meu caso é passado por construtor.

Agora vamos ao Fragment que irá criar o custom adapter, objetos da classe instrumento e irá criar e implementar o loader. Por favor, analisem o código pois ele está TODO comentado. Vou dispensar explicações pois elas estão no código.

Classe **InstrumentoListFragment**

```
public class InstrumentoListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Instrumento>> {
    /** String usada ao se registrar mensagens de log. */
    private static final String TAG = "InstrumentoTcTpListFragment";
    /** O ID unico do Loader. ID's dos Loaders sao especificos para a Activity ou Fragment em que eles residem. */
    private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

    /** Referencia para a classe que contem a logica do banco de dados. */
    private static SQLiteDatabase bancoDeDados;
    /** Referencia a interface callback no qual iremos interagir com o LoaderManager. */
    private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Instrumento>> loaderCallbacks;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        /*
         * A Activity ou Fragment (que implementa a interfce LoaderCallbacks<D>) e o objeto callback do qual iremos interagir com o LoaderManager.
         * O LoaderManager usa a implementação de LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks para notificar o cliente dos eventos do Loader.
         */
        loaderCallbacks = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onActivityCreated( savedInstanceState );


        /*
         * Inicializa o Loader com o id "LOADER_ID" e callback 'loaderCallbacks'. Se o Loader nao existe, um e criado. Caso contrario, o Loader ja existente e reutilizado.
         * O chamada ao initLoader assegura que o loader está inicializado e ativo. São duas as respostas a essa chamada:
         * Se o loader especificado já existe, o último loader criado será reutilizado.
         * Se o loader especificado não existe, o initLoader inicia o método onCreateLoader dentro de LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.
         * Aqui é onde você implementa código para instanciar e retornar um novo loader.
         * Em ambos os casos, o LoaderManager ira gerenciar o Loader sobre o ciclo de vida da Activity/Fragment, ira receber qualquer novos Loaders uma vez que estiverem completados,
         * e ira relatar estes novos dados de volta para o objeto 'loaderCallbacks'.
         * OBS: Deveríamos utilizar "initLoader()", mas como queremos que o Loader seja recarregado caso volte a partir de outro Fragment, então mudamos para "restartLoader()".
         */
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader( LOADER_ID, null, loaderCallbacks );
    }

    // ---------------------------------- INICIO dos metodos das interfaces implementadas ----------------------------------
    /*
     * Instancia e retorna um novo Loader para um dado ID.
     * É um método de fábrica que simplesmente retorna um novo Loader. O LoaderManager vai chamar esse método quando ele for o Loader pela primeira vez.
     */
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Instrumento>> onCreateLoader( int id, Bundle args ) {
        Log.d( TAG, "onCreateLoader()!" );

        return new IntrumentoTcTpLoader( getActivity().getApplicationContext() );
    }

    /*
     * Chamado quando um loader criado préviamente tem seu carregamento finalizado.
     * Este método é geralmente onde o cliente irá atualizar a interface do usuário do aplicativo com os dados carregados.
     * O cliente pode (e deve) assumir que novos dados serão retornados a este método cada vez que novos dados são disponibilizados.
     * Lembre-se que este é o trabalho do Loader, monitorar a fonte de dados e realizar os carregamentos assíncronos reais.
     * O LoaderManager receberá esses carregamentos uma vez que tenham concluído, em seguida, passar o resultado para o método onLoadFinished do objeto callback
     * para o cliente (ou seja, a Activity/Fragment) para usar.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished( Loader<List<Instrumento>> loader, List<Instrumento> data ) {
        Log.d( TAG, "onLoadFinished()!" );
        InstrumentoAdapter instrumentoAdapter = new InstrumentoAdapter( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), data );
        setListAdapter( instrumentoAdapter );
    }

    /*
     * Chamado quando um loader criado préviamente está sendo resetado, fazendo com que seus dados fiquem indisponíveis.
     * É chamado quando os dados do Loader está prestes a ser resetado. Este método dá a você a oportunidade para remover
     * quaisquer referências a dados antigos que podem não estar mais disponíveis.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset( Loader<List<Instrumento>> loader ) {
        Log.d( TAG, "onLoaderReset()!" );

        ((InstrumentoAdapter) getListAdapter()).setList( null );
        setListAdapter( null );
    }
    // ---------------------------------- FIM dos metodos das interfaces implementadas ----------------------------------

    // ---------------------------------- INICIO das classe privadas que estende AsyncTask ----------------------------------
    /**
     * Loaders é uma classe abstrata que executa o carregamento assíncrono de dados. Enquanto Loaders são ativos eles devem monitorar a fonte de seus dados e entregar
     * novos resultados quando o conteúdo mudar.
     * Clientes de Loaders devem, em regra, realizar qualquer chamada para um Loader a partir da thread principal do seu processo (isto é, a thread principal).
     * As subclasses de Loader (como AsyncTaskLoader), irá muitas vezes, realizar o seu trabalho em uma thread separada, mas ao entregar seus resultados este também deve ser feito na thread principal.
     * <br><br> Subclasses geralmente deve implementar pelo menos onStartLoading (), onStopLoading (), onForceLoad (), e onreset ().
     * <br><br> A maioria das implementações não deve derivar diretamente dessa classe, mas em vez disso, herdar AsyncTaskLoader.
     * <br><br>
     * <b>Uma aplicação que usa loaders tipicamente incluirá o seguinte:</b><br>
     * • Uma atividade ou fragmento <br>
     * • Uma instância do LoaderManager <br>
     * • Um CursorLoader para carregar dados guardados por um ContentProvider. Alternativamente, você pode implementar sua própria subclasse de Loader ou AsyncTaskLoader para carregar dados de outra fonte. <br>
     * • Uma implementação de LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks. Isso é necessário para que seja criado novos loaders e gerenciar suas referências para loaders existentes. <br>
     * • Uma forma de mostrar os dados do loader, como um SimpleCursorAdapter. <br>
     * • Um data source, como um ContentProvider quando usando o CursorLoader. <br>
     * <br>
     * O LoaderManager gerencia um ou mais instâncias de Loader dentro da atividade ou fragmento. Existe apenas um LoaderManager por atividade ou fragmento.
     * Você tipicamente inicializará o Loader dentro do onCreate() da Activity ou dentro do onActivityCreated() dentro do Fragment.
     */
    private static class IntrumentoTcTpLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Instrumento>> {

        // Referência para os dados dos Loader's aqui.
        private List<Instrumento> mData;

        // (1°) Chamado depois de onCreateLoader().
        public IntrumentoTcTpLoader( Context ctx ) {
            /*
             * Loader's podem ser usados em várias Activitys (assumindo que eles não estão vinculados a um LoaderManager), por isso nunca mantenha referencia para o contexto diretamente.
             * Isso fará com que cause um vazamento no contexto da Activity inteira. O construtor da superclasse irá armazenar uma referência para o contexto da aplicação ao invés disso e,
             * pode recebê-lo com uma chamada a getContext().
             */
            super( ctx );

            Log.d( TAG, "Construtor do Loader!" );
        }

        /**
         * (3°) Chamado depois de onStartLoading(). <br><br>
         * Este método é chamado em uma thread de background que realiza o carregamento assíncrono dos dados.
         *
         * @return Os dados que serão entregue ao cliente
         */
        @Override
        public List<Instrumento> loadInBackground() {
            Log.d( TAG, "loadInBackground()!" );
            List<Instrumento> dados = new ArrayList<Instrumento>();

            // TODO: Realiza uma consulta aqui e adiciona os resultados para "dados"
            Cursor result = bancoDeDados.query( InstrumentoTcTp.NOME_TABELA.texto, null, "Clausula WHERE com ?", "Argumentos da Clausula WHERE", null, null, null );

            // Percorre o cursor obtendo todos os dados e criando um objeto com os dados retornados.
            while ( result.moveToNext() ) {
                long id = result.getLong( result.getColumnIndex( InstrumentoTcTp.COLUNA_ID.texto ) );
                String nome = result.getString( result.getColumnIndex( InstrumentoTcTp.COLUNA_NOME.texto ) );
                String numeroSerie = result.getString( result.getColumnIndex( InstrumentoTcTp.COLUNA_NUMERO_SERIE.texto ) );

                // Cria um objeto instrumento com os dados armazenados no banco de dados.
                Instrumento instrumento = new Instrumento( id, nome, numeroSerie );
                // Adiciona o objeto instrumento a lista de instrumentos
                dados.add( instrumento );
            }

            return dados;
        }

        /**********************************************************/
        /**  Entrega os resultados para o  **/
        /** ****************************************************** */

        /**
         * (4°) Chamado depois de loadInBackground(). Após finalizar chama onLoadFinished(). <br><br>
         * Chamado quando há novos dados para entregar para o cliente (listener registrado).
         * A superclasse vai cuidar de entregá-lo; a implementação aqui apenas acrescenta um pouco mais de lógica.
         *
         * @param data Os dados que serão entregues ao cliente
         */
        @Override
        public void deliverResult( List<Instrumento> data ) {
            Log.d( TAG, "deliverResult()!" );
            // Verifica se o Loader foi redefinido. Isto é, ou o Loader não foi iniciado pela primeira vez, ou seu método reset() foi chamado.
            if ( isReset() ) {
                if ( data != null ) {
                    // Ignora o resultado e invalida os dados.
                    releaseResources( data );
                }
            }

            // Mantem uma referência para os dados antigos para que ele não coletado pelo "Garbage collector".
            // Devemos protegê-lo até que os novos dados sejam entregues.
            List<Instrumento> oldData = data;
            mData = data;

            if ( isStarted() ) {
                // Se o Loader está em um estado iniciado, entregamos imediatamente o resultado para o cliente. O método de superclasse fará isso para nós.
                super.deliverResult( data );
            }

            // Neste ponto, podemos liberar os recursos associados a "oldData", se necessário; agora que o novo resultado foi entregue sabemos que não precisamos mais dele.
            if ( oldData != null ) {
                releaseResources( oldData );
            }
        }

        /*****************************************************************/
        /** Implementação dos comportamentos dos estados do Loader *******/
        /** ************************************************************ */

        // (2°) Chamado depois depois do construtor do Loader
        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            Log.d( TAG, "onStartLoading()!" );
            // Se atualmente temos um resultado disponível, entregá-lo imediatamente.
            if ( mData != null ) {
                deliverResult( mData );
            }

            // Se os dados foram alterados desde a última vez que foi carregado ou não está disponível, inicie uma carga.
            if ( takeContentChanged() || mData == null ) {
                // Quando o observer detectar uma alteração, ele deve chamar onContentChanged() no Loader, que fará com que a próxima chamada para takeContentChanged()
                // retorne verdadeiro. Se este é sempre o caso (ou se os dados atual é nulo), forçamos uma nova carga.
                forceLoad();
            }
        }

        // Chamado quando a Activity/Fragment não está mais vísivel, por exemplo.
        @Override
        protected void onStopLoading() {
            Log.d( TAG, "onStopLoading()!" );
            // O Loader está em um estado parado, então nós devemos tentar cancelar o atual Loader (se houver).
            cancelLoad();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReset() {
            Log.d( TAG, "onReset()!" );
            // Assegura que o Loader tenha sido parado.
            onStopLoading();

            // Neste ponto podemos liberar os recursos associados com "mData" se necessário.
            if ( mData != null ) {
                releaseResources( mData );
                mData = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCanceled( List<Instrumento> data ) {
            Log.d( TAG, "onCanceled()!" );
            // Tentativa de cancelar o carregamento assíncrono atual.
            super.onCanceled( data );

            // O carregamento foi cancelado, nós devemos liberar os recursos associados com "data".
            releaseResources( data );
        }

        /**
         * Função auxiliar para cuidar de liberar recursos associados a um conjunto de dados ativamente carregado.
         * Para uma List simples, não há nada o que fazer aqui. Para algo como um Cursor, nós teríamos que fechá-lo neste método.
         * Todos os recursos associados com o Loader devem ser liberados aqui.
         *
         * @param data Os dados ativamente carregado.
         */
        private void releaseResources( List<Instrumento> data ) {
            Log.d( TAG, "releaseResources()!" );
        }
    }
    // ---------------------------------- FIM das classe privadas que estende AsyncTask ----------------------------------
}
```

Comment: Por que esta resposta precisa estar separada?

Comment: @bigown colocar em uma resposta só não dá, porque o número de caracteres limites é excedido.

Comment: Provavelmente porque é muito longa. Você deveria enxugar a resposta.

Comment: @bigown impossível enxugar a resposta nesse caso, sei que sai um pouco dos padrões do Stack Overflow, mas é o único jeito de ajudar neste caso.